# Edit a blank datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am adding a blank datagrid to allow users to add there own information to it, but when I click to edit the fields that have been added by the user through a button click event, I get the dreaded 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.  I have looked through the similar questions with this error, but can't for the life of me resolve my issue.  I understand it is to do with not having itemsource set for the datagrid but I am at a loss where I can add this in to solve my problem.  Hopefully someone can show me the error of my ways.  Thanks for your help as always.

```
XAML

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ResultsDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,356,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="134" Width="835" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StationID" Header="Station ID"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Pointnumber" Header="Point Number"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Description" Header="Description"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Velocity" Header="Velocity (MilliSeconds)"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Status" Header="Status"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="AddResult" Content="Add Result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="752,495,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="AddResult_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="RemoveResult" Content="Remove Result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="832,495,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Click="RemoveResult_Click"/>
</Grid>

C#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGridTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class AddResultRow
        {
            public string StationID { get; set; }
            public string Pointnumber { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Velocity { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }

        private List<AddResultRow> addnewrow()
        {
            List<AddResultRow> result = new List<AddResultRow>();
            result.Add(new AddResultRow()
            {
                StationID = "",
                Pointnumber = "",
                Description = "",
                Velocity = "",
                Status = ""
            });

            return result;
        }

        private void AddResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ResultsDataGrid.Items.Add(addnewrow());
        }

        private void RemoveResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = ResultsDataGrid.SelectedItem;
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                ResultsDataGrid.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would hardly recomment to get used to the MVVM pattern. You don't have to do this in the codebehind with direct access to your controls. Things get easier when using MVVM.

Comment: Thanks mm8, Yep MVVM is the way to go, I will be implementing it going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add objects to the `Items` collection of the `DataGrid` if you want to be able to edit the items. Instead you should set the `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection<AddResultRow>` and add items to this one:

```
public class AddResultRow
{
    public string StationID { get; set; }
    public string Pointnumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Velocity { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<AddResultRow> _items = new ObservableCollection<AddResultRow>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = _items;
    }

    private AddResultRow addnewrow()
    {
        return new AddResultRow()
        {
            StationID = "",
            Pointnumber = "",
            Description = "",
            Velocity = "",
            Status = ""
        };
    }

    private void AddResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _items.Add(addnewrow());
    }

    private void RemoveResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = ResultsDataGrid.SelectedItem as AddResultRow;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            _items.Remove(selectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```